# Re-establishing an RPC connection in spring

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, corda

I am running a spring server which connects to a corda node via RPC , currently I am initializing the connection when we initialize the server. what is the best practice in terms of being able to reconnect to rpc if rpc node goes down ? do I just poll and check if the rpc is diconnected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is discussed to some degree in the [Reconnecting RPC Clients](https://docs.corda.net/clientrpc.html#reconnecting-rpc-clients) section of the docs on interacting with a node.

> In the current version of Corda the RPC connection and all the
>   observervables that are created by a client will just throw exceptions
>   and die when the node or TCP connection become unavailable.
>
> It is the client’s responsibility to handle these errors and reconnect
>   once the node is running again. Running RPC commands against a stopped
>   node will just throw exceptions. Previously created Observables will
>   not emit any events after the node restarts. The client must
>   explicitly re-run the command and re-subscribe to receive more events.
>
> RPCs which have a side effect, such as starting flows, may have
>   executed on the node even if the return value is not received by the
>   client. The only way to confirm is to perform a business-level query
>   and retry accordingly. The sample runFlowWithLogicalRetry helps with
>   this.
>
> In case users require such a functionality to write a resilient RPC
>   client we have a sample that showcases how this can be implemented and
>   also a thorough test that demonstrates it works as expected.

There is currently a dead link to `ReconnectingCordaRPCOPs` which has been moved [here](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/master/client/rpc/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/client/rpc/internal/ReconnectingCordaRPCOps.kt)